# Apparmor error after mysql folder relocation

Tags: mysql

I relocated the mysql folder. I used [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a-mysql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-16-04).

I can not start the mysql service and I have this error message

```
Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
Aug 26 02:53:19 ubuntu audit[1345]: AVC **apparmor="DENIED**" operation="open" profi                                                 le="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/1345/status" pid=1345 comm="mysqld" requested_                                                 mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=109 ouid=109
Aug 26 02:53:19 ubuntu kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1503741199.505:43): apparm                                                 or="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/1345/status"                                                  pid=1345 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=109 ouid=109
Aug 26 02:53:19 ubuntu audit[1345]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profi                                                 le="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=1345 comm="mysqld" re                                                 quested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=109 ouid=0
Aug 26 02:53:19 ubuntu audit[1345]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profi                                                 le="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/1345/status" pid=1345 comm="mysqld" requested_                                                 mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=109 ouid=109
Aug 26 02:53:19 ubuntu kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1503741199.513:44): apparm                                                 or="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/syste                                                 m/node/" pid=1345 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=109 oui                                                 d=0
Aug 26 02:53:19 ubuntu kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1503741199.513:45): apparm                                                 or="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/1345/status"                                                  pid=1345 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=109 ouid=109
Aug 26 02:53:19 ubuntu audit[1345]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" prof                                                 ile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/ssd/ubuntu.lower-test" pid=1345 comm="mysqld" requ                                                 ested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=109 ouid=109
Aug 26 02:53:19 ubuntu audit[1345]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" prof                                                 ile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/ssd/ubuntu.lower-test" pid=1345 comm="mysqld" requ                                                 ested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=109 ouid=109
Aug 26 02:53:19 ubuntu kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1503741199.661:46): apparm                                                 or="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/ssd/ubuntu.lower                                                 -test" pid=1345 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=109 ouid=                                                 109
Aug 26 02:53:19 ubuntu kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1503741199.661:47): apparm                                                 or="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/ssd/ubuntu.lower                                                 -test" pid=1345 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=109 ouid=                                                 109
Aug 26 02:53:19 ubuntu kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1503741199.665:48): apparm                                                 or="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/ssd/ubuntu.lower                                                 -test" pid=1345 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=109 ouid=                                                 109
Aug 26 02:53:19 ubuntu audit[1345]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" prof                                                 ile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/ssd/ubuntu.lower-test" pid=1345 comm="mysqld" requ                                                 ested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=109 ouid=109
Aug 26 02:53:19 ubuntu audit[1345]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" prof                                                 ile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/ssd/ibdata1" pid=1345 comm="mysqld" requested_mask                                                 ="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=109 ouid=109
Aug 26 02:53:19 ubuntu kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1503741199.685:49): apparm                                                 or="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/ssd/ibdata1" pid                                                 =1345 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=109 ouid=109
Aug 26 02:53:20 ubuntu systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exit                                                 ed, status=1/FAILURE
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: I have a very similar problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I followed the following steps to change the default data directory in mysql:

I have the configuration of the system as follows

> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.19
>
> Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

The steps are as follows:

1. Stop the mysql server `service mysql stop`
2. Edit the file `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` and edit the `datadir` field to point to new location.

   For example `datadir         = /data/mysql`
3. Then copy the content of `/var/lib/mysql` to new location:

   ```
   cp -pr /var/lib/mysql /data
   ```
4. Then edit the `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld` file. Remove `/var/lib/mysql` and add the new `datadir` location. In my case it is

   ```
    # Allow data dir access
    /data/mysql/ r,
    /data/mysql/** rwk,
   ```
5. Restart apparmor service `systemctl restart apparmor`
6. Restart the mysql service `service mysql start`

   The above steps worked for me, I hope it will work for you too.

Comment: Thanks, meanwhile I have found this link also :     https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a-mysql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-16-04.  It seems it was better to modify the last line in the alias, and a restart is needed in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Always check the Apparmor status

1. `sudo service apparmor status`
2. If it is not active, use `journalctl -xe`, and verify which profile has problems.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: [Mysql Broken After Apt Upgrade](https://warlord0blog.wordpress.com/2018/01/18/mysql-broken-after-apt-upgrade/)

```
$ sudo vi /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld

    ...
      /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/ r,
      /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/* r,
      /sys/devices/system/node/* r,
      /etc/mysql/*.cnf r,
      /run/mysqld/* rw,
    ...

$ sudo systemctl reload apparmor.service
$ sudo systemctl start mysql.service
```